# Is "to circuit" a common verb in colloquial language?

Tags: verbs, word-usage

My boss asked me to have a look at a presentation he'll be giving next week; checking if he didn't forget anything.
While skimming over the document, the following sentence was somehow bothering me:

> ... in order to circuit the problem.

The use of *circuit* as a verb seemed odd to me. I first checked Merriam Webster's and Oxford's Learner's Dictionaries but they don't have listed *circuit* as a verb. The advanced editions of both dictionaries define the verb.

Neither the Corpora of Contemporary American English nor the British National Corpus has an entry on using *circuit* as a verb, but 10k and 2.5k, respectively, uses as a noun.

I incidentally mentioned to my boss that I'd chosen *to circumvent*, *to handle* or *to deal*. Subsequently, he asked a colleague who's native English whether she would understand the meaning of *circuit*. She agreed.

Surprisingly, she didn't say that *circuit* would be an odd choice. Well, I think I had posed the question in a different way, namely not asking about "being understandable" but rather about "is it natural to use *circuit* as a verb".

Is *circuit* acceptable as a verb in ordinary language or is it - as corpora are suggesting - an uncommon verb?

Comment: More common for *to circumvent* is *to short-circuit*.

Comment: @GEdgar Well, from [OALD](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/short-circuit_2) I understand something completely different to what *to circuit* intend to mean.

Comment: It is better to say “Neither . . . has” than to say “Both . . . do not have”.

Comment: Most likely it was intended to be either *circumvent* or, to a lesser extent, even *short-circuit*, not just *circuit*.

Comment: Or perhaps *skirt* (to avoid, go around the edge of, or keep distant from).

Answer (score 1):

The OED shows that [***circuit***](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/33202) has been a verb since around 1550.  It derives from the same word as a noun, which is documented to have been used for around 200 years before its use as a verb. The verb means:

> 1. **a.** *trans.* To go, pass, move, or travel round; to make the circuit of, compass about.
>      
>      **†b.** *fig.* To compass in thought, circumvent, get round. *Obs.*
> 2. *intr.* To go or move in a circuit.

Here is a transitive example, the latest citation given:

> - 1879   R. A. Proctor *Pleasant Ways Sci*. v. 119  
>    Some..comet, circuiting the sun in about eleven years.

And here is the only intransitive citation provided:

> - *a*1613   T. Overbury *Characters: Noble Spirit* in *Wks.* (1856) 61   
>   He circuits his intents, and seeth the end before he shoot.

I would not say this is a common verb, but documentation for it certainly exists.

Comment: However, *circuit* for *circumvent* (which is what the snippet appears to be saying) is marked as obsolete.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Oh, is that what the OP was meaning? I couldn’t quite tell.

Comment: Well, as said in my question I also found some entries in several dictionaries. You just found another one. That's not really satisfying.

Comment: Is it possible - as a plain language learner - to access OED?

Comment: @Em1 [Right now, yes](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/3904/2085). But the OED’s entry shows that the circumvent/short-circuit sense is obsolete.